# Netflix Viewing History

Tags: netflix

I am looking for the ability to list all viewing history for a defined user with some useful filtering(by date, by category, LastWatched, etc).

Is anyone familiar enough with the API to tell me if this exists?

Comment: Here is the URL for the API docs. Sorry I do not know how to do this but wanted to share: http://developer.netflix.com/docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netflix seems to have [removed this functionality from its API](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/08/31/netflix-removing-rental-history-from-public-api/). Speculation holds that this was related to a [class-action lawsuit regarding user privacy](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2012/07/class-action-lawsuit-settlement-forces-netflix-privacy-changes/). They have not said whether the functionality will be restored.